# Random from array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, random, arr

I want to know how do random function while the values of the random are from an array that exists in the program (pointer int).
My code looks like:

```
v=rand() %((array[0] - array[size_c]) + 1);
```

but the value of `v` does not belong to array.
Thank you.

Comment: Generate a random index between 0 and `size_c`; then take the value from the array at that index.

Comment: Imagine the array contains two values, an elephant and a seagull. What do you want `v` to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
int rand_number =  rand() % size;  
v = array[rand_number];
```

where size is the size of the array and  *v* is your random element from the array

and of course you will need to include **cstdlib**

and if you want different random each time you run the program you should add this line of code :

```
  srand (time(NULL));
```

this will initialize random seed and for the time(NULL) you will have to include **time.h**

for more info visit :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/